# Real Valued Function:finding number of solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> If $f(x)$ is a real valued function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-xy-1$ for all real $x$ and $y$ such that $f(1)=1$ then how to find the number of solutions of $f(n)=n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Do you assume continuity too?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: The function may or may not be continuous.I don't think it affects the problem as such..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is rather immediate that $n=1$ is the only solution.

Since $$f(2) = f(1+1) = f(1) + f(1) - 1- 1 = 0$$ you can use induction to prove that $f(n) \le 0$ for every $n \ge 2$ because
$$f(n+1) = f(n) + f(1) - n \cdot 1 - 1 \le 1 - n - 1 = -n \le 0$$ provided that $f(n) \le 0$.

Comment: Well done! You beat me to it!

Comment: And you beat me too.